# Ranked and Clustered Full Text Search

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to develop a ranked full-text search. The idea is to query two different columns from two different tables and return the "match score" of both.

I'd like the result to be clustered. I mean, the `score_question` would show the results `ORDER BY DESC`, same with `answer_question`. I want the results to show only the rows where whether `answer_score`or `question_score` is >= 0.1.

How would I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_questions(psearch text)
  RETURNS TABLE (answerid INTEGER, questionid INTEGER, score_question REAL, score_answer REAL) AS $func$
BEGIN
  return QUERY
  SELECT DISTINCT publications.publicationid as answers ,questions.publicationid as questions, ts_rank_cd(
                                                 to_tsvector('english', questions.title),
                                                 plainto_tsquery('english', psearch)
                                             ) AS score_question, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', publications.body),
                                                                             plainto_tsquery('english', psearch)) AS score_answer
  FROM questions, publications INNER JOIN answers ON publications.publicationid = answers.publicationid
  WHERE to_tsvector('english', questions.title || '' || publications.body) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', psearch)
  GROUP BY publications.publicationid, questions.publicationid;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here are my results

```
answerid | questionid | score_question | score_answer 
----------+------------+----------------+--------------
       70 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
      116 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
      143 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
      124 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
      130 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
       60 |         32 |              0 |          0.1
       60 |         27 |              0 |          0.1
       60 |        129 |              0 |          0.1
       60 |         23 |            0.2 |          0.1
       60 |        122 |              0 |          0.1
       60 |         31 |              0 |          0.1
      144 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
       53 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
      143 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
      116 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
       54 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
       65 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
       53 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
      144 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
       65 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
       60 |         21 |              0 |          0.1
       54 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
       60 |         10 |              0 |          0.1
       60 |        150 |            0.1 |          0.1
       60 |        141 |              0 |          0.1
      124 |         23 |            0.2 |            0
       60 |         19 |              0 |          0.1
      130 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
       60 |        135 |              0 |          0.1
       70 |        150 |            0.1 |            0
(30 rows)
```

Comment: *I'd like the result to be clustered. I mean, the score_question would show the results ORDER BY DESC, same with answer_question.* Your expected output doesn't seem sorted in any way. Please clarify on that further. -- BTW **if** your function is that simple, consider using [`LANGUAGE SQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) instead.

Comment: Another sidenote: your `WHERE` clause could be written like `(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(questions.title, '')) || to_tsvector('english', coalesce(publications.body, ''))) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', psearch)` which could allow [weighting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-DOCUMENTS), or you could use 2 `@@` matching, combined with `OR` to allow indexing too.